# Uploading files with PHP_SELF forms

Tags: php, forms, post

I am trying to create an admin panel directory creator for storing photos.  I have followed a tutorial but with tweaking it to my preference and I cannot get files to upload, though the directory creates just fine.  Here is the code, can you hint at what I've done wrong and if I'm approaching this the best way please?  I'm not entirely convinced setting paths as '../../../' is the best approach.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <label>Album name:</label><span class="req">*</span>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="album_name">
    <br />
    <input type="file" name="upload" /><br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242880" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $album = $_POST['album_name'];
    if(mkdir("../images/album/" . $album, 0700, true) && mkdir("../images/album/" . $album . "/album_cover", 0700, true)){
        echo "Album directory created successfully";
    }else{
        echo "Album directory failed";
    }
}

$target_path = "../images/album/" . $album . "/album_cover/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['upload']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['name'], $target_path)){
    echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['upload']['name']) . " has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have move the temporarily uploaded file to the directory, hence use `tmp_name`, not `name`

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
                                         ^
```

And `$target_path` should contain a valid file name as well, with its extension. Remove `basename`

```
$target_path = $target_path . $_FILES['upload']['name'];
```

**move_uploaded_file**

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

Comment: This has worked, thank you so much.  Have I coded this okay?  Should any of it be placed separately or within a function or anything?